# Shuffling a deck of cards multiple times in Go

Tags: go

I am new to go and am trying to learn by doing exercises including building out some deck of card functionality. I have a function that shuffles a deck of cards. How can I write a function so that I can shuffle the same deck of cards `n` times? Would I have to use pointers with this? Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Suit struct {
    label string
    value int
}

type Rank struct {
    label string
    value int
}

type Card struct {
    Suit
    Rank
}

type Deck []Card

func getPerm(n int) []int {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))
    return r.Perm(n)
}

func (d Deck) shuffle() Deck {
    finalDeck := Deck{}

    perm := getPerm(len(d))

    for _, j := range perm {
        finalDeck = append(finalDeck, d[j])
    }

    return finalDeck
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to shuffle the deck in place you can take advantage of the standard library [rand Shuffle](https://godoc.org/math/rand#Shuffle).

To do this you need to provide the length of the deck and in addition a swap function so that the shuffle function is able to actually shuffle the deck.

We also can add a for loop to add the ability to shuffle as many times as we want.

This can be done through this

```
func (d *Deck) shuffleN(n int) {
    for k := 0; k < n; k++ {
        rand.Shuffle(len(d), func(i, j int) {
            d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i]
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Go methods can only change value of struct they were called on ONLY if they receive it as a pointer. See [Go by Example: Methods](https://gobyexample.com/methods).

If you make receiver of `shuffle()` to be `(d *Deck)` (a pointer to Deck) the method can then mutate (shuffle) the deck itself instead of returning a new shuffled `Deck`. In method body you then need to assign your `finalDeck` to `d` instead of returning it (or work in place with `d` without the helper deck). Every time you call `anyDeck.shuffle()` then it will change `anyDeck` so you will do it `n` times.

Note: if you intend to make `shuffle()` usable outside `main` package (public) it needs to start with capital `S`. I will use that in my "pseudocode" below:

```golang
func (d *Deck) Shuffle() {
   // shuffle d here (and it will change the deck .Shuffle() was called on)
}

// somewhere else in code
...
deck := Deck{}
deck.Shuffle()
```

From there you can extend `func Shuffle(n int)` to take number of shuffles and embed `n` rounds in function body (or you can make `func ShuffleN(n int)` which will call original `Shuffle()` `n` times.